# Codenameone: working on one projekt on two computers impossible

Tags: codenameone

When using the Codenameone Starter Project and placing it on our internal Cloud Server the project is working properly only on the Computer where it was first opened. How can we change that?

Comment: I do this with git all the time. Make sure you don't add to the cloud server all the stuff that's ignored by gitignore that maven might be looking for. All the hidden files, etc. What's the full error message you're getting?

Comment: Notice you can edit your question and should place the stack trace there. Not as a new answer.

Comment: It looks like we're trying to grab a lock to access the CSS file but it's held by some other application. Probably the IDE from the other machine.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to us trying to grab a lock on the checksum file and its failing probably due to it being held by another IDE. Typically this file shouldn't be shared and shouldn't be in version control: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/CodenameOneDesigner/src/com/codename1/designer/css/CN1CSSCLI.java#L828

The file is called `.cn1_css_checksums`.